# How to get list of all methods of java file in Intelli J plugin development

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working on Intelli j  plugin which will get list of all the methods in java file and add my code in first line every methods and then save the file.

I have did this same for eclipse plugin development. But not able to get good reference links and documentation for plugin development in Intelli j

Please share link or provide sample code example how I can do this in Intelli j.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at getAllMethods() in class com.intellij.psi.PsiClass.

Some links that could help you

http://programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.intellij.psi.PsiMethod

https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5179397#5179397

http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2011/09/developing-plugin-intellij-idea-some-tips-and-links/